# Stretch background image with border image

Tags: css, border

The following image represents the desired outcome.

[image: Black or colored background with unique edges]

Typically I'd apply such case using 3 divs:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="edge left"></div>
    <div class="content">background color or image stretched here</div>
    <div class="edge right"></div>
</div>
```

This sounds like an overuse of semantics, so I decided to try using `border-image`, and this is the end result:

[image]

But, if I set a background color, it will act as a background for the borders too (can be solved using JPEG instead of PNG with a white background -but this isn't a solution-).

Any ideas or suggestions? Is the use of `border-image` recommended in the first place (any browser rendering variability?).

The image used and code are below:

[image]

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Test data Test data Test Data</a></li>
</ul>

#nav {
    border-width: 0px 38px;
    border-image: url(images/nav-border.png) 0 50;
    height: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y7g7w1b3/

Comment: Can you show us the code (and upload the image) that you used to produce the second screenshot?

Comment: please share your css also or create a fiddle

Comment: I have updated the question with the code and image. A fiddle link is added as well

Comment: @Ken: Actually the `background-color` can be clipped such that it doesn't cover the borders. I have added that option also to my answer (just in case you're interested in that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: Using fill and stretch for border image**

You can do this with `border-image` property itself by using the following settings:

- The value `fill` for `border-image-slice`. (Make sure that slice is less than half the width of the original image). You can find more details about this option in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice).
- The value `stretch` for `border-image-repeat`.

This works in IE11, Edge, Firefox v45, Opera v36, Chrome v51 (dev-m).

```css
#nav {
  border-width: 0px 38px;
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5foMd.png);
  border-image-width: 34px 98px;
  border-image-slice: 17 48 fill;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  height: 30px;
}
#nav li {
  line-height: 30px;
}
#nav li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Test data Test data Test Data</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Solution 2: Using background color**

> But, if I set a background color, it will act as a background for the borders too

You can actually clip the `background-color` such that it doesn't cover the borders. This option can work as long as the shape's background is a solid color.

```css
#nav {
  border-width: 0px 38px;
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5foMd.png) 0 50;
  background-color: rgb(34,34,34);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  height: 30px;
}
#nav li {
  line-height: 30px;
}
#nav li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Test data Test data Test Data</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use border image, instead I would use :before and :after. This creates 2 additional elements before and after your container.

Code below:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.container:before,
.container:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 50px;

}
.container:before{ right:100%: }
.container:after{ left: 100%; }
```

This will create the before and after elements for your container on each side. Then you can style the two elements as required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate on the reasons that made you steer away from using border image

Comment: `:before` and `:after` is not really a replacement for `border-image`, which usually does (or at least can do) much more that just appending 2 elements on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 1px `background-image` to act as your `background-color` (I used black in my example, embedded as base64) then combine `background-size`, `background-repeat` and `background-position` to achieve your goal:

Something like:

```
#nav {
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    border-width: 0px 38px;
    border-image: url(images/nav-border.png) 0 50;
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d743nck8/)

Comment: Very interesting approach indeed! Though I believe the use of 'background-position' can be neglected.